# Powershell get-content text file and loot to run msinfo32.exe

Tags: powershell, msinfo32

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\output\output.txt
$output = '\\PCname\c$\output\'
$output1 = '.txt'
($output2 =$output+$computers+$output1)
msinfo32.exe /report $output2 /computer $computer
```

What I am getting is the msinfo32.exe /report $output2 /computer $computer is reading the first PCname and only that name and writing the file name is each PCname with a space between each of them. Sorry for what most will seem to be a simple question I just started using PS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two issues here.

1. To properly concatenate strings into a path, you need you use `Join-Path`
2. You're getting only the first computer name because you aren't looping through your list of computers.

Quick & dirty revision (assumes that each computer name is on its own line in `output.txt`)

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\output\output.txt;  
$output = '\\PCname\c$\output\';  
$output1 = '.txt';  
$computers | foreach-object {
    $output2 = (join-path -path $output -childpath $_) + ".txt";  
    msinfo32.exe /report $output2 /computer $_;  
}
```